# string no more then 3 spaces allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Hello I'm pretty new into python and i was wondering if there is a better to make sure the input:

1. not include any weird characters such as ("#%^')
2. include only letters (exclude numbers too)
3. between 3-21 characters
4. any "-" or "_" will become space
5. 3 spaces is allowed in the input

basically its a city name input and i think no city is really that weird to exclude one of the rules above. if I'm wrong or there is a better way to look at this or code this please tell me.

```
city = input("where are you from: ").title()
cnt_space = 0
city = "".join(x for x in city if x.isalpha() or x.isspace())
for i in city:
    if i.isspace():
        cnt_space += 1
while cnt_space > 3 or len(city) > 22 or len(city) < 3:
    city = input("enter a valid city between 4-21 characters allowed 3 space: ")
    city = "".join(x for x in city if x.isalpha() or x.isspace())
    cnt_space = 0
    for i in city:
        if i.isspace():
            cnt_space += 1
        elif i == "-" or i == "_":
            i = " "
            cnt_space += 1
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: First, don't make those assumptions about city names. What if somebody from "1 Decembrie, Romania" or "10th of Ramadan, Egypt" wants to use your application? Second, what do you mean by "better" what improvements are you hoping to make? How is your current implementation not suiting your needs?

Comment: Assuming that city names can be captured with the ASCII subset is wrong. For example, Krakow is really “Kraków”. And what about Chinese cities? Or Russian?

Comment: Have a look through this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_and_cities_with_100,000_or_more_inhabitants/country:_A-B and see how many city names break your assumptions. I found a few on the first page.

Comment: Hmmm,
I think free input without constraints is best. you might strip off trailing and leading white space though, and replace multiple white spaces with single ones.

If you know the country, then you might have a lookup table / database with all existing cities and look for the closest fit and ask the user if no match is found whether the closest fit is what was intended.
but even if no match was found you should allow to accept the users input. Perhaps the city or town is new or got renamed and is just not in your data base

Comment: OK i see what you are saying but i have another question this information goes to a file that comes back to the script how can i make sure this information stays valid? not include weird names such as: "   a" or "! 4 ^blabla"